# Enumerable.Last<T>() and C# arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, ienumerable

Say I have a simple array:

```
double[] myDoubleArray = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Is this as performant:

```
double last = myDoubleArray.Last();
```

as this?

```
double last = myDoubleArray[myDoubleArray.Length - 1];
```

Will Last() enumerate over the entire array even when it can make the above optimization?

If I passed some other IEnumerable (say one that was yielded), Last() would *have* to enumerate the sequence.  I prefer using Last(), because code looks cleaner, but I would not make a sacrifice if it enumerates the sequence.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it won't iterate all over elements. Here's the code of Enumerable.Last() from reflector. As you see, it makes such optimization

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource current;
                do
                {
                    current = enumerator.Current;
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

No, `Last` *without* a predicate optimizes for the `IList<T>` case, including single-dimensional arrays.

*With* a predicate, it doesn't perform the optimization. In particular, it doesn't work backwards from the end (which could alter the results due to exceptions).

It's still going to be *slightly* faster to access the last element directly, but `Last()` is more readable and will only be "constant time" different - it won't change an O(1) operation to O(N) in this case.

For more about `Last`, see my [Edulinq blog post about it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx).

Note that the optimization is *not* documented, so arguably you shouldn't rely on it. In practice, I can't imagine it changing to become O(N) :)

Comment: Ok, I believe that (I can see the performance effect, and I can see it in the source). But this is not documented, though (unfortunately, as you pointed out many times before, the documentation around the standard LINQ operators is seriously lacking)

Comment: Its a little disappointing that the one with the predicate doesn't try to enumerate in reverse for `IList<T>`...

Comment: @Martinho: Yes, I was just adding the documentation bit.

Comment: @Kragen: I can see both sides of it to be honest. The optimization in LINQ to Objects generally treads a fine line.