# Always access data[0] as newest data

Tags: c#

I have an array of a million elements and I'm going to be running through it simulating it as live data, by making a current index as the "right now" and incrementing it to simulate new data coming in.

I'll be doing a great deal of calculations on the right now data, and data X bars to the past.

I'm wondering if there is a convenient way to abstract this to accessing today's data at someDataType[0] and 1 bar ago as someDataType[1] and so on?

I'm new to programming so I'm not really sure what is and what isn't possible. Ideally this data type would not have to copy data from the array to the datatype, rather it could store all the data itself and skip the array or somehow point to the array. And it will definitely have to be able to access the data in the same way as arrays, and not have to iterate over itself to get to some point like a list would need to.

I really have no clue if this is possible in any way, shape, or form. Thus I'm asking. Thanks for any input! :)

Comment: what you have done? can you share your code?

Comment: Well there is not much I can share that can make the question clearer.  The easiest solution that I would like would be to change what array[0] points to. But I don't think that is possible. And thus I'm seeing if there are alternatives. Of course I could always use a variable so today would equal array[today] and yesterday/older data would equal array[today -1]. But since my project will be so large, I'm looking for a more elegant approach/abstraction.

Comment: Assume that it is possible (it is), and then show us how far you got when you hit a wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you want to add new items, then using an array directly is probably not the best choice (unless the newest item should overwrite the oldest item). A better choice would be a `List<T>`.

Now, what you want to create is a “reversed” collection: it will contain a `List<T>` and:

- its indexer will access the reverse index in the backing list
- its add method (possibly called `AddFirst()`) will add to the end of the list
- its `GetEnumerator()` method will return reversed enumerator

With all these requirements fleshed out, the code almost writes itself:

```
class AddFirstList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> m_list = new List<T>();

    public void AddFirst(T item)
    {
        m_list.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerable.Reverse(m_list).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return m_list.Count; }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return m_list[Count - index - 1]; }
    }
}
```

(If you're not on .Net 4.5, remove the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not on Net 4.5 so I removed that part. Additionally I got an error saying the "Using the generic type System.collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> requires 1 type arguments". I fixed that by adding a using System.Collections; - So all is working now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need dynamic sizing on your structure, so a good choice would be [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) found in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1); // keep adding
```

It provides indexed access just as an array, but you can keep adding elements as necessary. If all you ever wanted to do was quickly retrieve the last element (in addition to normal random access via the index), you could use the `Last()` extension method, [which is optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595777/enumerable-lastt-and-c-sharp-arrays) for the `IList<T>` interface (and which is what `List<T>` implements) to directly return the last element without needing to enumerate the entire sequence.

However, it sounds like you want something that is more akin to full reverse index access. For that, you might have to code it. For reusability, you can make this an extension method in your project and use it wherever you need it. Something like this should fit your need.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T FromEnd<T>(this IList<T> list, int position)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("list cannot be null or empty");
        }

        return list[(list.Count - 1) - position];
    }
}
```

And using it is simple.

```
var myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int item = myList.FromEnd(1);
Debug.Assert(item == 4);
```

Of course, the wrinkle here is that this doesn't lend itself well if you wanted to loop over it in a `foreach` (you could still use a standard `for`). If using a foreach, you could simply loop use `foreach (var item in myList.Reverse()) { }`, or you could utilize an approach as coded in svick's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want index 0 to be the 'current data', and index 1 to be the previous data.

You can achieve this by writing your own class that encapsulates the million-element array. Then you can specify the index that is `right now` and add that to every indexing. For example:

```
public class DataArray
{
    readonly Object[] data;

    int rightNow;
    public int RightNow
    {
        get { return this.rightNow; }
        set { this.rightNow = value; }
    }

    public DataArrat(Object[] data)
    {
        // TODO: Check that data is not null.
        this.data = data;
    }

    // This is called an 'indexer':
    public Object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO: Check whether (index + this.rightNow) is in the valid range.
            return this.data[index + this.rightNow];
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this for example:

```
// Initialize the DataArray:
Object[] millionElementArray /* = from somewhere, e.g. */ = new []
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var data = new DataArray(millionElementArray);

// Start at bar 8:
data.RightNow = 8;

// Use the data:
Object currentData = data[0];
Object futureData = data[-1];
Object pastData = data[1];

// Go to the next bar:
data.RightNow--;

// Use the data:
Object currentData = data[0];
Object futureData = data[-1];
Object pastData = data[1];

// Rinse and repeat...
```

Note that you should replace `Object` by the type of data you are using, or make the class generic.

Comment: If you're making a new collection, you *really* should make it generic.

Comment: @svick: I always make my collections generic. I chose not to do that in this case because the poster said "I'm new to programming so I'm not really sure what is and what isn't possible". Putting generics in there is in this case not requires or necessary, and may complicate things for him.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please elaborate why?